# Rendering exception occurred: Jinja variable 'dict object' has no attribute 'data'

Tags: nginx, jinja2, salt-stack

Getting error while changing content in nginx.conf

**/etc/salt/master.d/reactor.conf**

```
reactor:
  - 'salt/beacon/*/inotify//etc/nginx/nginx.conf':
    - /srv/reactor/web-remediate.sls
```

**/srv/reactor/web-remediate.sls**

```
{% if data['data']['id'] %}
  web_state_run:
    local.state.apply:
      - tgt: {{ data['data']['id'] }}
      - arg:
        - webserver.nginx
{% endif %}
```

**salt-master -l debug**

**log**

```
[DEBUG   ] Initializing new IPCClient for path: /var/run/salt/master/master_event_pull.ipc
[DEBUG   ] Sending event: tag = salt/beacon/minion1.vagrant.net/inotify//etc/nginx/nginx.conf; data = {'path': '/etc/nginx/nginx.conf', '_stamp': '2017-09-23T12:21:17.586647', 'id': 'minion1.vagrant.net', 'change': 'IN_MODIFY'}
[DEBUG   ] Gathering reactors for tag salt/beacon/minion1.vagrant.net/inotify//etc/nginx/nginx.conf
[DEBUG   ] Compiling reactions for tag salt/beacon/minion1.vagrant.net/inotify//etc/nginx/nginx.conf
[DEBUG   ] compile template: /srv/reactor/web-remediate.sls
[DEBUG   ] Jinja search path: ['/var/cache/salt/master/files/base']
[ERROR   ] Rendering exception occurred: Jinja variable 'dict object' has no attribute 'data'
[ERROR   ] Failed to render "/srv/reactor/web-remediate.sls": 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/salt/utils/reactor.py", line 71, in render_reaction
    data=data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/salt/state.py", line 329, in render_template
    **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/salt/template.py", line 95, in compile_template
    ret = render(input_data, saltenv, sls, **render_kwargs)

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/salt/renderers/jinja.py", line 70, in render
    **kws)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/salt/utils/templates.py", line 164, in render_tmpl
    output = render_str(tmplstr, context, tmplpath)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/salt/utils/templates.py", line 428, in render_jinja_tmpl
    buf=tmplstr)
SaltRenderError: Jinja variable 'dict object' has no attribute 'data'
```

Answer (score 2):

I have modified the reactor configuration file's condition line from {% if data['data']['id'] %} to {% if data['id'] %} in /srv/reactor/web-remediate.sls and now the reactor is working fine.

just i assumed that the below line's data dictionary has contain 'id' key only, so i skipped ['data']

```
 [DEBUG   ] Sending event: tag = salt/beacon/minion1.vagrant.net/inotify//etc/nginx/nginx.conf; data = {'path': '/etc/nginx/nginx.conf', '_stamp': '2017-09-23T12:21:17.586647', 'id': 'minion1.vagrant.net', 'change': 'IN_MODIFY'}
```

modification:

```
 From:

  {% if data['data']['id'] %}
   web_state_run:
     local.state.apply:
       - tgt: {{ data['data']['id'] }}
       - arg:
         - webserver.nginx
 {% endif %}


 To:

 {% if data['id'] %}
 web_state_run:
   local.state.apply:
     - tgt: {{ data['id'] }}
     - arg:
       - webserver.nginx
 {% endif %}
```

output:

```
 Sending event: tag = salt/beacon/ranjith3.salt.az/inotify//etc/nginx            /nginx.conf; data = {'path': '/etc/nginx/nginx.conf', '_stamp': '2017-09-28T11:03:55.261016', 'id': 'ranjith3.salt.az', 'change': 'IN_IGNORED'}
 [DEBUG   ] Gathering reactors for tag salt/beacon/ranjith3.salt.az/inotify//etc/nginx/nginx.conf
 [DEBUG   ] Compiling reactions for tag salt/beacon/ranjith3.salt.az/inotify//etc/nginx/nginx.conf
 [DEBUG   ] compile template: /srv/reactor/web-remediate.sls
 [DEBUG   ] Jinja search path: ['/var/cache/salt/master/files/base']
 [PROFILE ] Time (in seconds) to render '/srv/reactor/web-remediate.sls' using 'jinja' renderer: 0.00302600860596
 [DEBUG   ] Rendered data from file: /srv/reactor/web-remediate.sls:

 web_state_run:
   local.state.apply:
     - tgt: ranjith3.salt.az
     - arg:
       - webserver.nginx
```

Comment: Thanks @rajithKumar, i apologize for update but i got same solution by myself.... really appreciate.